# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, api, dart, postman, strapi

I am try to post an note to my API in Strapi but I have that error
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

that is my code

```
Map<String, String> header = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer ${sharedp!.getString('token')}"
};
    addPosts() async {
      var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(post_note),
        body: {
          "data": {
            "title": "upload api",
            "content": "upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
            "userid": sharedp!.getString('id')
          }
        },
        headers: header,
      );
      var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
      print(responsebody);
      return responsebody;
    }
```

then that how I make post in postman

```
{
    "data":{
    "title":"upload api",
    "content":"upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
    "userid":1
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of sharedp!.getString('id')? Is it where you get the error?

Comment: is SharedPreferences i use it to get id to link note with the user that have make the post

Comment: At the beginning of your code, can you await for the response of sharedprefences and add it to a value, then use it inside json? Like this, var idString = await sharedp!.getString('id'); and in your json, "userid": idString. Can you try that?

Comment: I already knew what is the error is look like nested json and i dont know how to deal with look at api is {data:{title: text, content : text, userid : id }}

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap the json in a model class and obtain what you want by doing the following,

```
class ApiRequestData {
/*
{
  "title": "upload api",
  "content": "upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
  "userid": 1
} 
*/

  String? title;
  String? content;
  int? userid;
  Map<String, dynamic> __origJson = {};

  ApiRequestData({
    this.title,
    this.content,
    this.userid,
  });
  ApiRequestData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    __origJson = json;
    title = json['title']?.toString();
    content = json['content']?.toString();
    userid = json['userid']?.toInt();
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['title'] = title;
    data['content'] = content;
    data['userid'] = userid;
    return data;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> origJson() => __origJson;
}

class ApiRequest {
/*
{
  "data": {
    "title": "upload api",
    "content": "upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
    "userid": 1
  }
} 
*/

  ApiRequestData? data;
  Map<String, dynamic> __origJson = {};

  ApiRequest({
    this.data,
  });
  ApiRequest.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    __origJson = json;
    data = (json['data'] != null) ? ApiRequestData.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final data = <String, dynamic>{};
    if (data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> origJson() => __origJson;
}
```

Now once you construct your ApiRequest modal object like following,

```
setState(() => _isLoading = true); // If you intend to display a ProgressIndicator in the body while loading..
var id = await sharedp!.getString('id');
var req = ApiRequest(
  data: ApiRequestData(
    title: "upload api",
    content: "upload api to the user and show it in the app by id",
    userId: id,
  ),
);
var response = await http.post(
  Uri.parse(post_note),
  body: jsonEncode(req.toJson()),
  headers: header,
);
var responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
setState(() => _isLoading = false); // To now display widgets with the loaded data..
```

Pretty sure this helps..

Comment: i still have this error in responsbody {data: null, error: {status: 400, name: ValidationError, message: Missing "data" payload in the request body, details: {}}}

Comment: Looks like there is an issue in your backend, first wrap your actual response in a dart object, parse it with actual backend response and check (rather validate) your status, accordingly look if there is a "data" object in your response body and then parse your response data payload..